# How to add a title to a toggle switch in html?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I am trying to add a title to a toggle switch above it in html. However, it is getting hidden behind the switch itself. When I increase the font, I do see it. But, I do not want to increase the font. Following is the code snippet and its results:

HTML:

```
<label className="hrow switch form-group pull-right">
   <input type="checkbox"><span className="slider round"></span>Active</input>
</label>
```

CSS (for the switch):

```
/* The switch - the box around the slider */ .switch {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 60px;
    height: 34px;
}

/* Hide default HTML checkbox */
.switch input {
    display: none;
}

/* The slider */
.slider {
    position: absolute;
    cursor: pointer;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: lightgray;
    -webkit-transition: .4s;
    transition: .4s;
}

    .slider:before {
        position: absolute;
        content: "";
        height: 26px;
        width: 26px;
        left: 4px;
        bottom: 4px;
        background-color: white;
        -webkit-transition: .4s;
        transition: .4s;
    }

input:checked + .slider {
    background-color: #85a3e0;
}

input:focus + .slider {
    box-shadow: 0 0 1px #85a3e0;
}

input:checked + .slider:before {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(26px);
    -ms-transform: translateX(26px);
    transform: translateX(26px);
}

/* Rounded sliders */
.slider.round {
    border-radius: 34px;
}

.slider.round:before {
    border-radius: 50%;
}
```

RESULTS:

[results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yvoyo.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try moving the label content outside of the input element and using the `for` attribute to ensure click pass through. This should be easier to style than what you were doing before.

```css
label.switch input {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<label class="switch" for="checky">
   Active
   <input id="checky" type="checkbox">
</label>
```

Note: You also have an error in your HTML. `className` should be `class` (edit: Except if you are using React)

Comment: Nope. I tried that earlier.. did not work then nor now. Adding "title" did not work either.

Comment: @asf I've updated the answer with a functioning code snippet

Comment: I was writing this code in ReactJS where I had to use it as 'className'.